# "Time on Server" on samba share kubuntu 17.04

Tags: kubuntu

I have a problem on my kubuntu.
I will accesss the file on my Windows with Linux. But I see

> time on server

and some workgroup

> could not connect to host for smb://...

Please help me.

I use kubuntu 17.04

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you already have the smbclient package. It is very common that access is blocked by the ubuntu firewall. Additionally check the permissions on the Windows server resource. In linux. 
Check firewall (you have open port 445 tcp)

In turn try to access through the IP. Then you can add such IP in the hosts file

check `smb://<ip-server>/<resource>`

Comment: I try disable my firewall on Linux (ufw disable) and on Windows. But there is no change. Is a wrong from my step?